# How can i create bucket and objects with not public access using boto3 in aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to create a bucket and objects with not public access i.e it should be private using boto3 python code how can I achieve it?

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=accessKey,
                       aws_secret_access_key=secretKey,
                       region_name=region)
   

 s3_bucket= s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    print('bucket created')
    print(s3_bucket)
    bucket_name = 'bucket123'
    response_public = s3_client.put_public_access_block(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration={
            'BlockPublicAcls': True,
            'IgnorePublicAcls': True,
            'BlockPublicPolicy': True,
            'RestrictPublicBuckets': True
        },
    )
    print("pubic",response_public)
```

Bucket created but getting

error: in public access as 'S3' object has no attribute 'put_public_access_block'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

As thought originally the boto3 version was a legacy version (1.9.42), this function is not available in that version as you can see from [this documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/s3.html).

**Original**

I ran it like so and everything successfully applied, I would suggest looking at indentation and verifying the version of Boto3 you're running.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')
    bucket_name= 'ohfihfhfeuhehfuhfeih'
    
    s3_bucket= s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name, CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1'})

    response_public = s3_client.put_public_access_block(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        PublicAccessBlockConfiguration={
            'BlockPublicAcls': True,
            'IgnorePublicAcls': True,
            'BlockPublicPolicy': True,
            'RestrictPublicBuckets': True
        },
    )
```

In short **your code is fine** (I added the region configuration because certain regions require this), there is another factor. Fix the indentation, check your boto3 version (and update if its old, the current version is 1.14.7).

Comment: I can confirm this function is not in that version of boto3: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/s3.html

Comment: how can i update the boto version should i use pip install boto3 == 1.14.7

Comment: Either run `pip install boto3 --upgrade` or the command you specified :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217367/discussion-between-mia-and-chris-williams).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is probably due to the fact that you are creating bucket called

```
bucket_name= 's3buck123'
```

but then you use different name to set `put_public_access_block`

```
bucket_name = 'bucket123'
```

Also the indentation is wrong, but I assume this is due to copy and paste to SO.